# What is the syntax for the Squeak FFI in the new Squeak (5.0)

Tags: smalltalk, ffi, pharo, squeak

I am trying to use the Squeak Foreign Function Interface.
All information I was able to find does not seem to apply to the new Squeak 5.0 because when I try e.g.:

```
add: a to: b
    " ( int ) add (int a, int b) ; "
    < cdecl: int 'add' ( int a, int b ) module: 'mydll'>
    ^ self externalCallFailed
```

which is derived from [this page](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/2426)'s:

```
apiInvalRect: aRect
    " ( void ) InvalRect (const Rect &star; badRect ) ; "
    < cdecl: void 'InvalRect' ( MacRect )  module: 'InterfaceLib'>   
    ^ self externalCallFailed.
```

then I get the error that it expects a `>` right after the `<`.

(I am using Squeak 5.0 on Windows with `SqueakFFIPrims.bundle` in its resources directory.)

Comment: FFI is not installed by default in the image, did you try anything to install it?

Comment: @aka.nice It is not? I only saw that my image has a SqueakFFIPrims.bundle in its directory and that i none of the websites I visited had any info that it had to be installed (and how?), also not in squeakMap. I would be very glad if you tell us how to install it and I hope that also solves the syntax error (I guess the plugin changes the parsing rules too?)

Comment: I usually load the latest FFI packages with Monticello from http://source.squeak.org/FFI.html that would be 'FFI-Kernel-dtl.28.mcz'  'FFI-Tests-EstebanLorenzano.8.mcz'  'FFI-Examples-ar.1.mcz'. There must be some Installer script which does the same work, but I don't remember where to find it, maybe ask google...

Comment: thanks i will try that - will report in a few minutes

Comment: There are some dependencies I am trying to resolve now...

Comment: Ah, the right order is 'FFI-Pools' 'FFI-Kernel' 'FFI-Tests' 'FFI-Examples'

Comment: that works thank you! please put  the info into your answer and i will accept it.    source.squeak.org/FFI.html    and      right order is 'FFI-Pools' 'FFI-Kernel' 'FFI-Tests' 'FFI-Examples'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to install FFI in the image, via Monticello.

The FFI package are located at http://source.squeak.org/FFI.html

You need to install 'FFI-Pools' first, then 'FFI-Kernel'. Then you can load 'FFI-Tests' and 'FFI-Example'.

Once FFI is installed in image, the correct syntax would be something like this:

```
add: a to: b
    " ( int ) add (int a, int b) ; "
    <cdecl: long 'add' ( long long ) module: 'mydll'>
    ^ self externalCallFailed
```

You don't specify the parameter names - they are implicitly taking the same position as the smalltalk method.

You have to replace int by long - it's the same on supported 32 bits platforms.

**EDIT** to load the FFI package in Squeak, you can type and execute (do it) this in a workspace:

```
(Installer repository: 'http://source.squeak.org/FFI')
    install: 'FFI-Pools';
    install: 'FFI-Kernel';
    install: 'FFI-Tests';
    install: 'FFI-Examples'.
```